# writestream to aws S3 (v3)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharp

I'm trying to use lambda to convert heic-files to jpeg-files. I am using [this layer](https://github.com/zoellner/sharp-heic-lambda-layer). I have tested this with the `GetObjectCommand()` and `PutObjectCommand()`, and it works perfectly.

I want to convert it to a readStream and writeStream, and use the upload function from `aws-sdk/lib-storage` to pipe the image through sharp and then upload it to the bucket. This is my code, I got it from [this website](https://obviy.us/blog/sharp-heic-on-aws-lambda/):

```
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import sharp from "sharp";
import stream from "stream";

const s3 = await new S3Client();

async function readStreamFromS3(Bucket, Key) {
  return await s3.send(
    new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket,
      Key,
    })
  );
}

function writeStreamToS3(Bucket, Key) {
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();

  return {
    writeStream: pass,
    upload: new Upload({
      client: s3,
      params: {
        Bucket,
        Key,
        Body: pass,
        ContentType: "image/jpeg",
      },
    }),
  };
}

function streamSharpHEIC() {
  return sharp().rotate().toFormat("jpeg").jpeg({
    quality: 80,
    mozjepg: true,
  });
}

export async function handler(event, context) {
  const readStream = await readStreamFromS3('my-bucket', 'sample.heic');
  const convertStream = streamSharpHEIC();
  const { writeStream, upload } = writeStreamToS3(
    'my-bucket',
    `converted.jpg`
  );

  readStream.Body.pipe(convertStream).pipe(writeStream);
  await upload;
}
```

The bucket exists, the sample.heic-file is in the bucket. It works with PutObjectCommand. Leaving out the `pipe(convertStream)` doesn't work either.

Am I doing something wrong?